# How to validate several userform textboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a workbook with userforms to write to several numeric and date fields. I need to validate the textbox control for proper numbers and dates.

Rather than replicate the validation for each textbox, I thought I would call a common subprocedure within the `BeforeUpdae` event of each textbox.

I have two problems.

1. If I execute the form and test using text in tbAmount box, it seems the ContolValidate procedure is not called.
   If I run it in break mode with a breakpoint on `Call ContolValidate(What, CurrentControl)`, it will step through that procedure.
2. Even though it steps through the procedure, the `Cancel = True` does not seem to work.
   If I paste the ContolValidate code directly in the BeforeUpdate, the `Cancel = True` does work.

This code is all on the userform.

```vb
Private Sub tbAmount1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim What As String
    Dim CurrentControl As Control

    What = "NumericField"
    Set CurrentControl = Me.ActiveControl
    Call ContolValidate(What, CurrentControl)
End Sub

Private Sub ContolValidate(What, CurrentControl)
    If Not IsNumeric(CurrentControl.Value) Then
        ErrorLabel.Caption = "Please correct this entry to be numeric."
        Cancel = True
        CurrentControl.BackColor = rgbPink
        CurrentControl.SelStart = 0
        CurrentControl.SelLength = Len(CurrentControl.Value)
    Else
        If CurrentControl.Value < 0 Then
            ErrorLabel.Caption = "This number cannot be negative."
            Cancel = True
            CurrentControl.BackColor = rgbPink
            CurrentControl.SelStart = 0
            CurrentControl.SelLength = Len(CurrentControl.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbAmount1_AfterUpdate()
    ErrorLabel.Visible = False
    tbAmount1.BackColor = Me.BackColor
End Sub
```

Comment: The code pasted by you has `End Sub` without a `private sub`. Could you please add that too ? Also, where does the reference to `Cancel`  variable come from within `ContolValidate` method ?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Not sure I understand.  The code has 3 Private Sub and 3 End sub encapsulation. And ```Cancel`` is a property of the control (i believe) i have read that it stops the control update to the control and it remains in focus, which is what you want with validation - do not let them leave the field unless it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** When your control is named `tbAmount1` and the code is in the code-behind module of the form, the trigger should fire.

**(2)** As @shahkalpesh mentioned in his comment, `Cancel` is not known in your validate-routine. Putting `Option Explicit` at the top of you code would show you that.
I would suggest to convert the routine to a function. In the code below, I return `True` if the content is okay and `False` if not (so you need to put a `Not` to the result to set the `Cancel`-parameter)

```
Private Sub tbAmount1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Cancel = Not ControlValidate("NumericField", Me.ActiveControl)
End Sub

Private Function ControlValidate(What, CurrentControl) As Boolean
    ControlValidate = False

    If Not IsNumeric(CurrentControl.Value) Then
        errorlabel.Caption = "Please correct this entry to be numeric."
    ElseIf CurrentControl.Value < 0 Then
        errorlabel.Caption = "This number cannot be negative."
    Else
        ControlValidate = True   ' Input is okay.
    End If
    
    If ControlValidate Then
        CurrentControl.BackColor = vbWhite
    Else
        CurrentControl.BackColor = rgbPink
        CurrentControl.SelStart = 0
        CurrentControl.SelLength = Len(CurrentControl.Value)
    End If
End Function
```

P.S.: I changed the name to `ControlValidate` - "contol" seems wrong to me...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. I figured that somehow the sub did not understand the Cancel, but was unsure how to make it do so. Your answer had one issue. ```ControlValidate``` returned an "Object variable or With block note set" error. This line ```If Not IsNumeric(CurrentControl.Value) Then``` didn't seem to like the ```Me.Control``` being passed to it. I just added ```Set CurrentControl = Me.ActiveControl``` back in, and it works great. Thanks for pointing out the "Contol" as well. (My vision is poor.) That would have eventually bit me.